# Cloud Run - BUILD_DOCKER_UNKNOWN // cant import python

Tags: python, docker, flask, google-cloud-platform, dockerfile

I am trying to put a nonweb python script on Cloud Run with a flask-service and i am totally new on Cloud Run and with Docker and Dockerfiles.
I need to import telegram and yfinance for this script.
In the Cloud Run editor pylint already says that it is not possible to import yfinance and telegram, but i installed both via pip install in the Cloud Run terminal.
The main.py worked locally on my pc, but dont know what is going on here...

I show you my main-file (main.py):

```
import yfinance as yf
import time
from telegram import Bot
from flask import Flask, request
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def my_stockscout():

    bot = Bot('thecorrecttoken')   
    
    def fetch_yfinance_data(ticker): 
        
     
        try: 
        
            #print ("Fetching", ticker)
            data = yf.Ticker(ticker)
     
            # download historic data 
            df = data.history(period="max", intervall="1d") 
     
            # fill NaN with previous values 
            df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace= True)
            
            
            #put Date to Column instead of index
            df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
     
            # save df to csv file 
            df.to_csv(f'./data/{ticker}.csv', sep=';', index=True, header=True)
            #print(f'Fetching {ticker} data complete.') 
            time.sleep(1) 
     
        
                
           
        
        # Ermittle MAX aus den gezogegenen Kursdaten und letzten Schlusswert
        
            allTimeMax = round(df['Close'].max(),2)
            #allTimeMaxRaw = df['Close'].max()
            #allTimeMaxDate = str(df['Date'].max(),2)
            maxRow = df['Close'].argmax()
            lastCloseValue = round(df['Close'].iloc[-1],2)
            allTimeMaxDate = df.iloc[maxRow].values[0]
            
        
        
        # Alarm einstellen
        # Wenn letzter Kurseintrag (heute) kleiner 20% - 40% von MAX-bisher, dann Alarm
        
        
            if  allTimeMax-(allTimeMax/100)*40 <= lastCloseValue <= allTimeMax-(allTimeMax/100)*20:
                stockinfo = "Der Kurswert - "+str(lastCloseValue)+" -  betraegt "+str(round(lastCloseValue/(allTimeMax/100),2))+" Prozent des AllTimeMax-Wertes "+str(allTimeMax)
                bot.send_message(chat_id=155358511, text="<a href='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+str(ticker)+"?p="+str(ticker)+"&.tsrc=fin-srch'>"+str(ticker)+"</a>: Regime Knappheit: "+stockinfo)
                pync.notify(stockinfo, title=str(ticker)+": Regime Knappheit!")
                
        
            elif lastCloseValue < allTimeMax-(allTimeMax/100)*40:
                stockinfo = "Der Kurswert - "+str(lastCloseValue)+" - betraegt "+str(round(lastCloseValue/(allTimeMax/100),2))+" Prozent des AllTimeMax-Wertes "+str(allTimeMax)
                bot.send_message(chat_id=155358511, text="<a href='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+str(ticker)+"?p="+str(ticker)+"&.tsrc=fin-srch'>"+str(ticker)+"</a>: Regime Eskalation: "+stockinfo)
                pync.notify(stockinfo, title=str(ticker)+": !Regime Eskalation!")
                
                
            else: 
                stockinfo = "Der Kurswert - "+str(lastCloseValue)+" - betraegt "+str(round(lastCloseValue/(allTimeMax/100),2))+" Prozent des AllTimeMax-Wertes "+str(allTimeMax)+" vom "+str(allTimeMaxDate)[:10]            
                #telegram_send.send(messages=["<a href='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+str(ticker)+"?p="+str(ticker)+"&.tsrc=fin-srch'>"+str(ticker)+"</a>: Normales Regime: "+text])
                pync.notify(stockinfo, title=str(ticker)+": Normales Regime")
                #bot.send_message(chat_id=155358511, text="<a href='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"+str(ticker)+"?p="+str(ticker)+"&.tsrc=fin-srch'>"+str(ticker)+"</a>: Normales Regime: "+stockinfo)
                
        
        except Exception as e: 
            print("Error fetching", ticker, "data: ", e)
            
    fetch_yfinance_data("IUSQ.DE")
    fetch_yfinance_data("IESZ.SW")      
    
    return 'ok',200
#my_stockscout()
if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT',8080)))
```

And here is the Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.9-slim

# Allow statements and log messages to immediately appear in the Knative logs
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED True

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn yfinance time telegram

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 main:app
```

If i run this in the Cloud Run emulator i got this output:

```
Starting to run the app using configuration 'Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally' from .vscode/launch.json...
To view more detailed logs, go to Output channel : "Cloud Run: Run/Debug Locally - Detailed"
Dependency check started
Dependency check succeeded
Unpausing minikube
The minikube profile 'cloud-run-dev-internal' has been scheduled to stop automatically after exiting Cloud Code. To disable this on future deployments, set autoStop to false in your launch configuration /home/oaorama/.vscode/launch.json
Update initiated
Build started for artifact oaorama
Build failed for artifact oaorama
Update failed with error code BUILD_DOCKER_UNKNOWN
build [oaorama] failed: exit status 1. Docker build ran into internal error. Please retry.
If this keeps happening, please open an issue..
Skaffold exited with code 1.
```

I tried with a different Python version, but it still is the same error output.

Maybe you guys have a clue? I am totally lost here...

Comment: Do you have docker installed? Did you try a docker build?

Comment: I have docker installed locally and i will try my script on my local docker, now. I hope this will give me some clues. Maybe it is not a Cloud Run problem ;-). Let's see.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem might be with launch.json file. Or you could put in the docker file and see where it errors out. If you don't see any outputs it might be somewhere else.

```
RUN echo "this does stuff"
```